# What are the values of the primary and secondary colors in CIE L*ab color space using D65 2° observer?

Tags: colors, color-space, lab-color-space

**Question**

Using `D65 illuminant` and a `2° observer`, what are the values of sRGB `red`, `green`, `blue`, `cyan`, `magenta`, and `yellow` in `CIE L*ab` color space?

Here are the coordinates of my white point:

```
95.047, 100, 108.883
```

**Problem**

I tried a dozen different tools (both free and paid, like Photoshop), and noticed not a single one can agree on what `red` (and the other colors) is in CIE Lab, even when using the same illuminant, observer, and white point.

**What I tried**

I made a benchmark using different tools. Here is a sample using the following online tools:

- [aspose.app](https://products.aspose.app/svg/color-converter/rgb-to-lab)
- [colorizer.org](https://colorizer.org/)
- [nixsensor.com](https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/)
- [cielab.io](https://cielab.io/)

```
┌───┬─────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│   │ Rgb         │ Lab (aspose.app)       │ Lab (colorizer.org)   │ Lab (nixsensor.com) │
├───┼─────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ R │ 255, 0, 0   │ 54.291, 64.644, 55.913 │ 53.23, 80.11, 67.22   │ 53.24 80.09 67.20   │
│ G │ 0, 255, 0   │ 87.819, -63.417, 64.79 │ 87.74, -86.18, 83.18  │ 87.73 -86.18 83.18  │
│ B │ 0, 0, 255   │ 29.568, 54.63, -89.624 │ 32.3, 79.2, -107.86   │ 32.30 79.19 -107.86 │
│ C │ 0, 255, 255 │ 90.666, -40.526, -11.9 │ 91.12, -48.08, -14.14 │ 91.11 -48.09 -14.13 │
│ M │ 255, 0, 255 │ 60.169, 74.832, -48.40 │ 60.32, 98.25, -60.84  │ 60.32 98.23 -60.82  │
│ Y │ 255, 255, 0 │ 97.607, -12.6, 74.715  │ 97.14, -21.56, 94.48  │ 97.14 -21.55 94.48  │
└───┴─────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

These results seem somewhat similar in the `L` channel, but the `a` and `b` values are inconsistent from one tool to the other.

Looking at the source from [cielab.io](https://github.com/ucarion/cielab.io/blob/master/src/color.ts), I can see they use the exact same illuminant, observer, and white point as I do.

```
const STD_ILL_D65: XYZ = { x: 0.950489, y: 1, z: 1.08884 };
```

So what is going on here?
Why can't I find anywhere a standard definition of red, green, blue, etc in CIE Lab using D65 illuminant and 2° observer?

Comment: At first glance, your question seems to be about color space and not programming. Later, you refer to some code but that code is on some other site and no information about which language that is or how it's implemented. [ask]

Comment: Thank you, this question is indeed 90% about color theory, and very little about concrete software implementation (although the end goal here is writing code). Sadly there doesn't seem to be a StackExchange website for color theory, as per the answers to this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194334/where-to-ask-a-question-about-colorspace-theory

Answer (score 2):

Your question has unfortunately an infinite amount of answers because they are an infinite amount of RGB spaces (thus the infinite quantity of primaries and secondaries).

You need to specify which RGB space your values are encoded with, ideally which gamut, whitepoint and colour component transfer function, Then, with that, you can obtain a single answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [sRGB specification](https://www.color.org/chardata/rgb/srgb.xalter), the XYZ coordinates of the `sRGB` primaries are

```
┌────┬──────┬──────┐
│ x  │ y    │ z    │
├────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 64 │ 0.33 │ 0.03 │
├────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 30 │ 0.6  │ 0.10 │
├────┼──────┼──────┤
│ 15 │ 0.06 │ 0.79 │
└────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Using the equations from [Bruce Lindbloom](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_XYZ_to_Lab.html), we can interpolate these coordinates to the `CIE L*a*b*` color space.

Assuming `L` is in range `[0, 100]`, `a` is in range `[-128, 127]`, and `b` is in range `[-128, 127]`, the coordinates of sRGB red, green, and blue in `CIE L*a*b*` using `D65 illuminant` and `2° observer` are

```
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│ 53.24080499 │ 80.09229045  │ 67.20312527 │
├─────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 87.73471268 │ -86.18270839 │ 83.17930383 │
├─────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 32.29701093 │ 79.18725441  │ -107.860155 │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it looks like the [nixsensor.com](https://nixsensor.com) values are correct, which also matches values from other places like [www.brucelindbloom.com](http://www.brucelindbloom.com/).

There are 2 issues with [aspose.app](https://www.aspose.app/) values:

1. The LAB values are using `D50 illuminant` (which is why `red L = 54.29`)
2. `A` & `B` are *percentages* out of `~125`, so instead of displaying `A = 80.81` (for `D50 illuminant`), they display `A = 80.81 / 125 = 64.6%`

I'm guessing [colorizer.org](https://colorizer.org) is just a rounding error.